# How do I change the color of this?

Tags: theme

And yet one more question. I am full of them. I doubt this will be my last.

On my page www.indigomeadowscrafting.com there is a gray bar at the top. How do I change that color? Where is it in the files? I have been through every file I can think of to change that color. I managed to get the rest of the tweaking done I needed but am at a complete loss for that top bar.

I like the bar, I just would like to change the color.

Thanks all!

Rachel

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gray bar is an background image

```
.header {
    background: url(../images/top-bg.png) repeat-x;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

path /skin/frontend/ma2/ante/images/top-bg.png

Take a look at [Chrome DevTools for CSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3HGJsNLQ1E) to learn how to debug css